# How can I extract nonzero values from tensor in keras

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, tensor, loss-function

I'm trying to manipulate some data, in Python, inside a custom loss function in Tensorflow.keras

Consider the following example:

`b = tf.constant([[0, 3, 1], [0, 5, 2]])`

I would like to erase the zero column, or to extract the non-zero ones, such that the final result would be a tensor

`[[3,1], [5,2]]`

I tried with tf.where, using a mask, but it does not maintain the shape, it just return a 1D tensor with the non zero values.
Furthermore, I need this to work for an arbitrary number of row, the only thing fixed is the number of columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this selects all columns with a sum > 0:

```
tf.transpose(tf.gather_nd(tf.transpose(b), tf.where(tf.reduce_sum(b, axis=0)>0)))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it seems to work even inside the loss function!